# Questions on usages of shared_ptr - C++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, shared-ptr

I have few questions on the best practices of using `shared_ptr`.

**Question 1**

Is copying `shared_ptr` cheap? Or do I need to pass it as reference to my own helper functions and return as value? Something like,

```
void init_fields(boost::shared_ptr<foo>& /*p_foo*/);
void init_other_fields(boost::shared_ptr<foo>& /*p_foo*/);

boost::shared_ptr<foo> create_foo()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<foo> p_foo(new foo);
    init_fields(p_foo);
    init_other_fields(p_foo);
}
```

**Question 2**

Should I use `boost::make_shared` to construct a `shared_ptr`? If yes, what advantages it offers? And how can we use `make_shared` when `T` doesn't have a parameter-less constructor?

**Question 3**

How to use `const foo*`? I have found two approaches for doing this.

```
void take_const_foo(const foo* pfoo)
{

}

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<foo> pfoo(new foo);
    take_const_foo(pfoo.get());
    return 0;
}
```

OR

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<foo> p_foo;
typedef const boost::shared_ptr<const foo> const_p_foo;

void take_const_foo(const_p_foo pfoo)
{

}

int main()
{
     boost::shared_ptr<foo> pfoo(new foo);
     take_const_foo(pfoo);
     return 0;
}
```

**Question 4**

How can I return and check for `NULL` on a `shared_ptr` object? Is it something like,

```
boost::shared_ptr<foo> get_foo()
{
     boost::shared_ptr<foo> null_foo;
     return null_foo;
}

int main()
{
     boost::shared_ptr<foo> f = get_foo();
     if(f == NULL)
     {
          /* .. */
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: The docs have a timing page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/smarttests.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the questions have been answered, but I disagree that a shared_ptr copy is cheap.

A copy has **different semantics** from a pass-by-reference. It will modify the reference count, which will trigger an atomic increment in the best case and a lock in the worst case. 
You must decide what semantics you need and then you will know whether to pass by reference or by value.

From a performance point of view, it's usually a better idea to use a boost pointer container instead of a container of shared_ptr.

Comment: Yep, you're right, copying ref-counted pointers can be expensive! +1

Answer (score 4):

1. Copying is cheap, the pointer doesn't take much space. The whole point of it was to make it small to allow usage in containers by value ( e.g. `std::vector< shared_ptr<Foo> >` ).
2. `make_shared` takes a variable amount of parameters, and is the prefered mechanicsm over constructing it yourself (just like `make_pair`). The advantage is readability, especially if passing temporaries and/or namespaces is involved:
3. [boost::const_ptr_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) as already suggested
4. smart pointers have overloaded operators and may be directly used in expressions evaluated to bool. Don't use `get`. For anything. Instead of comparing `p.get` to anything, compare a empty pointer instance ( `my_ptr != boost::shared_ptr< MyClass >()` )

AD.2

```
func_shared( boost::shared_ptr<my_tools::MyLongNamedClass>( 
    new my_tools::MyLongNamedClass( param1, param2 ) );
```

versus

```
func_shared( boost::make_shared<my_tools::MyLongNamedClass>( param1, param2 ));
```

Comment: The *biggest* advantage of `make_shared` is not readability, but efficiency: `shared_ptr` requires dynamic memory allocation for the shared reference count, so that `shared_ptr<...>(new ...)` involves two (often expensive) memory allocations.   `make_shared`, on the other hand, allocates enough memory for the object plus the reference count at the same time, and is therefore more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, the copy is absolutely cheap. Besides holding the pointer, there is (usually) one other data member for the shared_ptr class - the use count.
2. Can't answer this, I generally use boost versions before make_shared was introduced (1.40?)
3. Use boost::const_pointer_cast
4. shared_ptr has operator==/!= defined. In your example above: if (f)

Answer (score 3):

1. Copying a shared_ptr now costs 32 bytes in stack copy and extra refcount increments/decrements. Decide whether it is cheap for you or not, but I see no reason why not to pass a const reference, especially that you already have a typedef for the ptr:
   `void f(const foo_ptr &myfoo)`
   especially given that the standard no-write-permissions parameter passing in C++ is const reference.
2. I would prefer having no functions that accept pointer that is not shared. This is similar (though not identical) to parameter passing semantics in Java and C#. Why dive into deciding every time how to pass an object, instead of having one standard way of doing it?
3. Use `if(p)` just as for regular pointers. The boolean conversion semantics is pretty neat.

Answer (score 2):

1. One of the basic reasons for the existence of shared_ptr is to be relatively cheap to copy.
2. There are versions of make_shared that take parameters (and if your compiler supports variadic templates, one that takes a variable parameter list).
3. It sounds like you're looking for const_ptr_cast?
4. To return a null pointer, you can pass '0' to the share_ptr ctor. To check for a null pointer, you can compare p.get() to 0.

Comment: for #4: you can compare `p` with 0 as well actually

Comment: @sbi and laura: yes, it's true that it has conversions built in, so most of the time you can treat it as if it was a normal pointer.